# General Term for this form Field

Tags: plugins, custom-field, css, forms, html

I'm trying to find out what you call a Field where you can select like lets say

What department do you want to contact?

then its Departments: 
         [Tech] [Sale's]

ect

[image]

I use Formidable forms and im just not sure how to go about making the form from the picture.
I For the love of me cant remember what its called when you use Text fields to select instead of Checkboxes/Radio Buttons

Comment: If you have an example you can use your browser debug tools to 'inspect' it, and see what they called it?

Comment: Its just a picture, Im just looking for the general term name , For what you would call this field, So that I can go about figuring out how to do this